# Default option in select and happening http

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I have problem with two things, how can I make in Select default option ? because with ng-model, he show only blank at this moment:

```
      <select class="form-control" ng-model="pageSize">
          <option value="5" selected>5</option>
          <option value="10">10</option>
          <option value="25">25</option>
          <option value="50">50</option>
          <option value="100">100</option>
        </select>
```

Second question is, how i can make event onChange in angular, that if someone choose some option in select, immediately send a request

Comment: Do not forget to accept the answer so that some other person who have the same query can easily get the right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the default option selected you need to assign value to your scope variable when the controller loads as

```
$scope.pageSize = "5";
```

Now for change detection when you select a option you can simply use the `ng-change` directive of AngularJS. Add that change function in HTML like this

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="pageSize" ng-change='optionChanged()'>
          <option value="5" selected>5</option>
          <option value="10">10</option>
          <option value="25">25</option>
          <option value="50">50</option>
          <option value="100">100</option>
</select>
```

And in the controller function you need to create this function like

```
$scope.optionChanged = function(){
    console.log($scope.pageSize);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `ng-selected` to pre-select an option and use 
`ng-change` to call a function every time option is changed

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){

  $scope.sendReq = function(pageSize){
    console.log(pageSize)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
 <select class="form-control" ng-model="pageSize" ng-change="sendReq(pageSize)">
          <option value="5" ng-selected="true">5</option>
          <option value="10">10</option>
          <option value="25">25</option>
          <option value="50">50</option>
          <option value="100">100</option>
        </select>
</div>
```